# Set cookie jar in Node.js HTTP POST request

Tags: node.js, cookies, curl

I need to send a HTTP POST request using Node.js' [Restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler).

Now my curl request to set the cookie jar file looks like this:

```
 curl -c '/tmp/mycookie' -d <data> http://myhost:3000/put
```

and to read cookies from like this:

```
 curl -b '/tmp/mycookie' -X POST http://myhost:3000/put1
```

How I can set *mycookie* on request object? Should this be request header?